# Heating of cyclic dicarboxylic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, heat

How do we predict the products formed when we heat cyclic dicarboxylic acids? I know that in case of aliphatic dicarboxylic acids we apply Blanc's rule and predict the product formed based on the number of carbons between the acid groups.

In case of aliphatic dicarboxylic acids:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\hline
n & \text{Product} \\
\hline
0 & \text{Oxalic acid} \\
1 & \text{Malonic acid} \\
2 & \text{Succinic acid} \\
3 & \text{Glutaric acid} \\
\ldots & \ldots \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Here $n$ is a number of carbons between $\ce{-COOH}$ groups.

I tried searching on the net but could not find a convincing answer. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere

Comment: Blanc's rule applies to heating dicarboxylic acids in acetic anhydride NOT just heating them.